# sane representation of lists in XML and JSON using MoXY

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, moxy

I need to expose a JAX-RS resource in XML and JSON, part of which will include passing in (potentially large) lists of integers.  I'm using MoXY as my JAXB / JSON provider.

The problem that I run into is that I cannot figure out how to expose a list of integers that works well in both XML and JSON.

If I use

```
@XmlList
@XmlElement(name = "Values", type = Integer.class)
protected List<Integer> values;
```

Then JSON is (un)marshaled as

```
...
"Values" : "0 1 2 4"
...
```

which is undesirable when dealing with large numbers of numbers.  If the @XmlList annotation is omitted, then the JSON is dealt with properly, but the XML

```
...
<Values>0 1 2 4</Values>
...
```

is parsed as [124] instead of [0, 1, 2, 4].

By using @XmlElementWrapper (and telling MoXY to "useWrapperAsArrayName")

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Values", required = true)
@XmlElement(name = "Value")
protected List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Good JSON is achieved

```
...
"Values" : [0, 1, 2, 4]
...
```

but this imposes the very tedious XML format of

```
...
<Values>
  <Value>0</Value>
  <Value>1</Value>
  <Value>2</Value>
  <Value>4</Value>
</Values> 
...
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to how to proceed?  I can't imagine this is an uncommon use-case, yet I am thoroughly stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of how you can handle your use case:

### Java Model (Foo)

This is a sample class to hold the property that you described in your question.

```
package forum23939109;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlList
    @XmlElement(name = "Values", type = Integer.class)
    protected List<Integer> values;

    public List<Integer> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Integer> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

### External Metadata (oxm.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum23939109">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Foo">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="values" name="Values"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

The demo code below demonstrates how to leverage the external mapping document in the creation of the `JAXBContext` that will be used to handle the JSON content.

```
package forum23939109;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create Instance of Domain Model
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(0);
        values.add(1);
        values.add(2);
        values.add(4);
        foo.setValues(values);

        // Marshal Object to XML Based on Annotations
        JAXBContext jcXML = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        Marshaller marshallerXML = jcXML.createMarshaller();
        marshallerXML.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshallerXML.marshal(foo, System.out);

        // Marshal Object to JSON Based on Annotations & External Mappings
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(3);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum23939109/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jcJSON = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);
        Marshaller marshallerJSON = jcJSON.createMarshaller();
        marshallerJSON.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshallerJSON.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <Values>0 1 2 4</Values>
</foo>
{
   "Values" : [ 0, 1, 2, 4 ]
}
```

Comment: That does the job, Thanks!  But... why?  I don't feel like I've told MoXY anything new here..

Comment: @mookpoint - All the external mapping file has done is told MOXy to remove the `@XmlList` from the property.